# Adjusting index in a vector in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, indexing, while-loop

I am writing a code in which the values of vector indexes are displayed as per the sorted order of the elements they hold:

For example:

```
values  -> 3 2 4 1 5
indices -> 1 2 3 4 5    //yeah I know C++ indexing starts with 0. Well, while printing, I will add 1

result  -> 4 2 1 3 5    //Bear with me. I know its confusing. I will clarify below
```

Now, the result has been obtained by sorting the elements and printing their earlier indices.

Like:

```
values(sorted)           -> 1 2 3 4 5
indices(before sorting)  -> 4 2 1 3 5
```

Now, there are many ways to do it with some suggesting to store the previous values and search and print the previous index, while others suggesting to create a new vector and copy the previous indices in it and then sorting them and.... (Well I didn't read further, 'cause that's definitely not how I was gonna proceed)

I tried a different approach while trying to not use a second vector.
So here's the approach:

```
while (!vec_students.empty()) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator iterator = std::min_element(vec_students.begin(), vec_students.end());
    std::cout << std::distance(vec_students.begin(), iterator) + 1 << " ";
    vec_students.erase(iterator);
}
```

Now in this approach, the problem I am facing is that once I use erase, the index of all elements decreases by a certain incrementing value. So this was the solution I thought of:

```
while (!vec_students.empty()) {
    static int i = 0;    //yeah I know standard static variables are initialised to 1.
    std::vector<int>::iterator iterator = std::min_element(vec_students.begin(), vec_students.end());
    std::cout << std::distance(vec_students.begin(), iterator) + i << " ";
    vec_students.erase(iterator);
    i++;
}
```

Now the thought goes like this:
Initial Solution:

```
vector:  2 3 1
expected output: 3 1 2 (For explanation refer above)
first index = indexof(min(2,3,1)) -> 2 (while printing add 1) -> 3
second index = indexof(min(2,3)) -> 0 (while printing....) -> 1
third index = indexof(min(3)) -> 0 (while...) -> 1
```

Then I realized that the vector size decreases which means, indices will decrease (by 1 in this case)

so I added the extra `i` thingy. 
Solution working:

```
vector: 2 3 1         i = 0
first index = indexof(min(2,3,1)) -> 3 -> add i -> 3 -> increment i -> i = 1
second index = indexof(min(2,3)) -> 0 -> add i -> 1 -> increment i -> i = 2
third index = indexof(min(3)) -> 0 -> add i -> 2 -> increment i -> i = 3
```

and the program ends.

But in the above case, instead of `3 1 2` I am getting `3 2 3` (first value right, rest incremented by 1)

What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: "Now, there are many ways to do it with some suggesting...(Well I didn't read further, 'cause that's definitely not how I was gonna proceed)" followed by "Also, is there any better logic available?" Yes, use one of the previously suggested ways.

Comment: *"//yeah I know standard static variables are initialised to 1."* they default initialized (with `0` in this case)

Comment: @John  good one. What I meant was that, if anyone can improvise my logic, i.e. without using another vector

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to make a new vector?

Comment: It's just that I want to use as less memory as possible. I like learning various new logics to some problems. Especially, ones with better space complexity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the index of all elements decreases by a certain incrementing value.

Not all, just the ones that come after the one you removed. Here's one way to do it without making another vector:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{3, 2, 4, 1, 5};
  auto const* beg = v.data();
  auto sz = v.size();
  while (sz--) {
    auto const min = std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << &*min - beg << ' ';
    *min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
  }
}
```

This won't work properly if you have `INT_MAX` in your vector. In any case, making a second vector could yield better solutions. An example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{3, 2, 4, 1, 5};
  std::vector<int const*> addresses;
  addresses.reserve(v.size());
  std::transform(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::back_inserter(addresses),
                 [](auto const& elm) { return &elm; });

  std::sort(addresses.begin(), addresses.end(),
            [](int const* const ptr1, int const* const ptr2) {
              return *ptr1 < *ptr2;
            });

  for (auto* p : addresses) {
    std::cout << p - v.data() << ' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But, I am still learning STL. Will you please elaborate on the working of last 2 lines?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 about `&*min - beg`: Because all elements are continuous in a vector, subtracting the address of the first element from the address of any element in that vector yields its index.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` means largest possible `int`. There cannot be an `int` larger than this. We set `*min` to largest possible value, so it does not become the minimum value again.

Answer (score 1):

You think you should add indices because the vector is shrink.

Well, not really, only those *after* the removed element should be effected.

---

example.

`[2,1,3] => [2,3]`

index of `2` remains at 0,

while index of `3` becomes `1` from `2`

---

Comment: Oh! Yeah right. But then the question arises, how do I overcome it?